# Django query to sort by a field on the latest version of a Many to Many relationship

Tags: python, django, django-queryset, django-orm

Let's say I have the following Django models:

```py
class Toolbox(models.Model):
    class Meta:
      constraints = [
          models.UniqueConstraint(
              fields=["name", "version"],
              name="%(app_label)s_%(class)s_unique_name_version",
          )
      ]

    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    version = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    tools = models.ManyToManyField("Tool", related_name="toolboxes")

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return f"{self.name}"

class Tool(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return f"{self.name}"
```

I want to write a query that fetches all Tools and returns them sorted by their latest toolbox's name. I know I can achieve this using the following code:

```py
tools = Tool.objects.all()
for tool in tools:
    tool.latest_toolbox = tool.toolboxes.order_by("-version").first()

tools = sorted(tools, key=lambda x: x.latest_toolbox.name)
```

Here's a unit test written in pytest-django to prove this works:

```py
from pytest_django.asserts import assertQuerysetEqual

def test_sort_tools_by_latest_toolbox_name():
    tool1 = Tool.objects.create(name="Tool 1")
    tool2 = Tool.objects.create(name="Tool 2")
    toolbox1_v1 = Toolbox.objects.create(name="A", version=1)
    toolbox1_v1.tools.add(tool1)
    toolbox1_v2 = Toolbox.objects.create(name="Z", version=2)
    toolbox1_v2.tools.add(tool1)
    toolbox2_v1 = Toolbox.objects.create(name="B", version=1)
    toolbox2_v1.tools.add(tool2)

    tools = Tool.objects.all()
    for tool in tools:
        tool.latest_toolbox = tool.toolboxes.order_by("-version").first()
    
    tools = sorted(tools, key=lambda x: x.latest_toolbox.name)
    assertQuerysetEqual(tools, [tool2, tool1])
```

However, the `Tool` table has thousands of records and this is taking minutes to execute. Is there a faster query I can write?

I've tried the following but it's returning duplicates and isn't sorting the tools correctly:

```
Tool.objects.order_by("toolboxes__name")
# <QuerySet [<Tool: Tool 1>, <Tool: Tool 2>, <Tool: Tool 1>]>
```

Comment: i think if you change your last query to Tool.objects.order_by("toolboxes__version").distinct() you would get the correct result

Comment: @Henty that doesn't do anything unfortunately

Comment: As for now, the toolboxes are ordered by id. Have you tried setting a different ordering? `ordering = ["name"]` in the `Meta` options. This way you don't have to get all the `Toolbox`es a `Tool` is related to. By the way, I do believe that the last query you've posted works fine, your only problem seems to be that they're duplicated, but they're correctly ordered, right? (`Tool 1 - Toolbox A | Tool 2 - Toolbox B | Tool 1 - Toolbox Z`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this approach using [**`Subquery`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/expressions/#subquery-expressions) and [**`OuterRef`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/expressions/#django.db.models.OuterRef):

```
from django.db.models import OuterRef, Subquery

toolbox_subquery = Toolbox.objects.filter(tools=OuterRef('pk')).order_by('-version')
tools_qs = Tool.objects.order_by(Subquery(toolbox_subquery.values('name')[:1]))
```

If you need the `name` of the latest toolbox other than for ordering, you can just put it in an annotated field:

```
tools_qs = Tool.objects.annotate(latest_toolbox_name=Subquery(toolbox_subquery.values('name')[:1])).order_by('latest_toolbox_name')
```

Each tool will then have an annotated field `latest_toolbox_name` that will have the name of their associated toolbox with the latest version.

Answer (score 0):

Use [prefetch_related](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related)

```
toolbox_qs = Toolbox.objects.order_by("-version")
tools_qs = Tool.objects.prefetch_related(Prefetch('toolboxes', query=toolbox_qs)
for tool in tools_qs:
    tool.latest_toolbox = tool.toolboxes.first()
```

or i think

```
tools_qs = Tool.objects.prefetch_related('toolboxes')
for tool in tools_qs:
    tool.latest_toolbox = tool.toolboxes.order_by("-version").first()
```

Not sure either of those will work out of the box but along those lines will work, basically instead of querying every Tools toolboxes, you prefetch all of the relations and then filter through them and thus doing 1 or 2 queries instead of many

Comment: I think `tool.toolboxes.first()` needs to be changed to `tool.toolboxes.all()[0]` otherwise `first()` will cancel the prefetch?

Comment: I think you could be correct but I'm not convinced either way haha would be nice to be corrected if its tried :)

Comment: I tried prefetch related but it didn't speed it up as much as I had hoped.